# composer install requirements error, and can't do composer update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, knpmenubundle

I'm trying to install `KnpMenuBundle` here's my current `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "thrace/form-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "dev-master",
        "thrace-project/media-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "dev-master",
        "imagine/imagine": "0.5.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try `composer install`, It gives me this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.5.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.5.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.5.x-dev requires knplabs/knp-menu-bundle dev-master -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I also can't do `composer update` since it will update my `composer.lock` and I don't want this to happen. Because I've specified some exact versions to use of `ThraceMediaBundle` and bundles that it depends on.

So i'm stuck with `composer install` which gives me the above error.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

When I try:

```
composer update knplabs/knp-menu-bundle:dev-master --dry-run
```

I get this output (I mysteriously removes `LiipImagineBundle`!)

```
Package "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle:dev-master" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Uninstalling liip/imagine-bundle (dev-master 4415054)

  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu (v2.0.1)

  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu-bundle (dev-master bdfc95d)

knplabs/knp-menu suggests installing pimple/pimple (for the built-in implementations of the menu provider and renderer provider)
knplabs/knp-menu suggests installing silex/silex (for the integration with your silex application)
```

---

**EDIT 2**

My bad, I forgot to add `LiipImaginBundle` inside composer.json.

Comment: You can do a partial update using `composer update <vendor>/<package>`

Comment: @kix I've edited the question with the output. Please take a look at it.

Comment: There's no mystery in removing `liip/imagine-bundle`, it's not required in your `composer.json`.

Comment: @kix Yea, I just noticed that. Please post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a partial update using `composer update <vendor>/<package>`.

Also, `liip/imagine-bundle` was autoremoved due to not being required in your `composer.json`.